# Trying to figure out what this is asking

Tags: python, arrays

'm trying to write a script that automates a process we do here in the office quite often. It involves copying .dlls from the location of where I want to put this script to folders such as /syswow64 and a couple other locations, and then registering them there. Now, being fairly new to python, I don't know how to do this yet. I know C++ well, but not Python. I considered doing this anyway in Python as it will help me learn it as I go along. I am certain I can figure most of it out

Comment: So the array is balanced as a whole if there is any element within it for which the condition is met?

Comment: It appears to be relative to a particular element.  If the elements below sum to the same as the sum of the elements above, then its balanced.  [4;1;3;5;5;3] - so this list is balanced around the first '5' in the list since 4+1+3 = 5+3

Comment: That being said, this question is far too localized to be of future use.

Comment: Also, it says "less than", so does that imply the list should be sorted before checking if it is balanced?

Comment: @mydogisbox It's basically a special case of finding the median value, I think.

Comment: Ah, I think you're right.  That is a very confusingly worded question.

Comment: @sr2222 Find the median value would have been a much better way to word this. Thanks guys

Comment: Actually, I don't think that's quite an accurate description.  I think the sequence `1, 3, 6, 7, 10` would be balanced at the `7` element, but the median is 6 and the mean is 5.4.  Finding the mean and the median would give you a better place to start searching for the balance point, but neither one is guaranteed to even be near the balance point.

Comment: @sr2222 so can the balance point be found by first finding the mean?

Comment: If I'm right, not exactly.  I think @9000 has the right idea in his answer though.

Answer (score 2):

To me, it reads like this.

Make a list of 10 random numbers in [0..4] range.

For each element of the list, check that the balance rule holds: find all elements <= current and sum them, find all elements > current and sum them, compare. If it does for every element, report the array as balanced.

This definition seems contradictory to me, though.

- If you include the current element into the "less than or equal to current" group (≤-group), then the maximal element has the whole list in the ≤-group, and none in the >-group, so it always breaks the balance.
- If you *do not* include the current element into ≤-group, the maximal element in list has all but itself in the ≤-group, and none in the >-group.
- If you include the current element in its own >-group, it sound silly!

The definition does not stop to be contradictory if, instead of ≤-group and >-group you use <-group and ≥-group; the minimal element always breaks the balance then.

Go ask your mentor about the exact formulation.

A skeleton of a program might look like this:

```
import random

the_list = [random.randint(0, 4) for _ in range(10)]

if is_balanced(the_list):
  print "Yes!"
else:
  print "No."

def is_balanced(the_list):
  # here's your assignment
```

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I'm looking for the element in which the array mean is equal to 2?